# Uploading a non-pdf file using jQuery AJAX causes issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle, http

I've been tasked with the creation of an html file uploader that has to create a POST request to our ORDS endpoint.

I've come up with a solution that works well for PDF files, but when i try to upload anything else issues start coming up.

This is my  code:

```js
$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (document.getElementById("fileinput").value != "") {
        AJAXSendRequest();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("alertfile").style.display = "block";
    }
    return false;
});

function AJAXSendRequest() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0]);
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0].type,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://192.168.0.145:7001/ords/dads/media_module/media/",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0].type,
            "filename": document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0].name,
            "inWHAT_DOC": tipo,
            "inID_DOC_INSIDE": document.getElementById("id").value.toString()
        }
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        document.getElementById("successfile").style.display = "block";
        // window.close();
    });
}
```

I get an HTTP201 no matter what kind of file i upload, but this is the result from reading an uploaded xml file

```xml
-----------------------------19718198955447
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="AutoResponder.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoResponder LastSave="2019-04-01T11:26:51.2600418+02:00" FiddlerVersion="5.0.20182.28034">
  <State Enabled="false" Fallthrough="false" UseLatency="false" />
</AutoResponder>
-----------------------------19718198955447--
```

The formData is somehow wrapped in this weird string which also shows up in the uploaded file **(but not in a pdf)** (the number changes with each request) and these two headers are always added at the top of the file.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="AutoResponder.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Is there anything i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Requests done with curl work without issues.

```sh
curl -X POST http://192.168.0.145:7001/ords/dads/media_module/media/ -H 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' -H 'Host: 192.168.0.145:7001' -H 'filename: testimgcurl.jpg' -H 'inID_DOC_INSIDE: 1240187' -H 'inWHAT_DOC: C Contratti Appalto' --data-binary @ch4.jpg
```

Comment: This seems to be a server side issue with how your request is being handled when the file is not a PDF mime type. Your JS is fine, and will not have anything to do with the type of response returned from the server (assuming the request is made correctly). That said, I would suggest you set `contentType: false` though.

Comment: Also note that the 'weird string' in the request is the boundary between the properties in the request; it's entirely normal.

Comment: Edited the question with additional information

Comment: The problem with the string is that it's showing up in the uploaded file too.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, i've ended up using XMLHttpRequest.

This is the working code.

```js
var file = document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0];
var data = new Blob([file], {type: file.type});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});
xhr.open("POST", "http://192.168.0.145:7001/ords/dads/media_module/media/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Host", "192.168.0.145:7001");
xhr.setRequestHeader("filename", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("inWHAT_DOC", tipo);
xhr.setRequestHeader("inID_DOC_INSIDE", id);
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.send(data);
```